# Any reason of not being able to have default variadic templates

Tags: c++

Does anyone know if there is any sensible rationale behind the decision of not being able to have default arguments for variadic templates? It's not difficult to imagine:

```
template<class T, class... Policies = Default_Policy>
class X
{
};
```

Comment: Sorry for swearing but this was seriously unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

It is valid for  a parameter pack  to contain zero things. How should the compiler choose when you write `X<T>`: `Policies = {}` or `Policies = {Default_Policy}`?

(And your syntax doesn't allow for default value with more than 1 item, but that's just syntax.)

Comment: Does “parameter pack” as a term actually exist to describe this? Is it commonly known? Googling didn’t find anything, and I’d never heard it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Not sure if it's common, but it's the proper term (n3290 §14.5.3/3).

Comment: #KennyTM it does allow for multiple values: Policies = {P1,P2,P3}

Answer (score 1):

It seems confusing to use default arguments, when the number of arguments given can vary. For example, how would you tell the compiler that you wanted to use this default, when instantiating the template? And how would the compiler know if you wanted

```
X<T, Default_Policy>
```

or

```
X<T, Default_Policy, Default_Policy>
```

without explicitly using the name "Default_Policy", etc. ?

This is (at least in my opinion) a good reason to not have default arguments for variadic templates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new language feature to have default arguments. Specializations and template aliases are enough.

```
template<template<typename...> class t, typename def, typename... a>
struct give_default {
  using type = t<a...>;
};
template<template<typename...> class t, typename def> 
struct give_default<t, def> {
  using type = t<def>;
};

template<typename... t>
using X_with_default = typename give_default<X, Default_Policy, t...>::type;
```

Comment: #Pubby, oh, I see. I was going for some mad and unreadable syntax (Policy = {P1,P2,P3}), without realizing that simpler/better/more natural way alrady exists, as you've proved. I feel really silly.